# Heroku not fetching from DB when scheduler running

Tags: heroku

This just cropped up recently. When the scheduler is running my site goes "empty" and posting to the site produces errors. This never happened a couple weeks ago. Something change with scheduler?

Ruby on Rails app.

```
1 -> 2x web
0 -> workers

Heroku Postgres :: Yellow
```

Paying 43ish a month.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a coincidence but Heroku just launched their new dynos. From a recent e-mail  "Heroku has new dynos types and pricing in public beta. These new dyno types and prices are scheduled to become generally available in June. Existing applications with more than a single 1x dyno as of the general availability date can opt-in to the new pricing through Jan 31, 2016. ..."  I don't know if this is the issue, but it might be something to ask them about.

Comment: I thought about that. Odd that when scheduler is running pages in the app render but missing some DB info. Posting to app throws an error while scheduler running.